# how can we use sed command to write \n in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When replacing string in file with other string having \n then when it replace it enters a line rather then writing \n in shell.

program-

```
string="status=\"translated\">NIRANJAN\\nKUMAR"
sed -i 's/status="translated">/'"$string"'   /g' text.txt
```

text files contains- status="translated">Fixes

output is:

```
status="translated">NIRANJAN
KUMAR
```

but i want `status="translated">NIRANJAN\nKUMAR`

please suggest me the steps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You already lost some backslashes during this assignment:

```
string="status=\"translated\">NIRANJAN\\nKUMAR"
```

The `\\` will be reduced to a single `\`, so you end up with `\n` in your sed command, resulting in a newline (on some versions of sed, at least).

To preserve them, use single quotes around the string literal:

```
string='status="translated">NIRANJAN\\nKUMAR'
```

Now your sed command should behave as you expect.

Comment: but i am facing problem when is use string as variable 
like- 
echo -n "enter"
read n  - niranjan\\nkumar

string='status="translated">$n'
echo $string is coming status="translated">$n 
but i want as status="translated">niranjan\nkumar

Comment: I don't understand the code in your comment - perhaps you need to update the code in your question if your real case is different.

Comment: If you want all newlines to output as \n you can use a different tool.  Pipe the output of the last command to `tr '\n' '\\n'`